# System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'System.Linq.Enumerable:<ToLookup`2>

Tags: xamarin.ios

here is my Code

```
public int GetUsersSqlCount()
{
    // Here i get the Error
    return this.GetUsersSql().Count();
}

public IEnumerable<CsUser> GetUsersSql()
{       
    return (from x in this._storage.CsUsers
           join y in this._storage.CeMitarbs on x.MitNr equals y.MitNr
           select x).OrderBy(x => x.KurzZch);
}
```

I get the following Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'System.Linq.Enumerable:<ToLookup`2>m__5A<Genesis.DataAccess.Schema.Mobile.V1.Wrapper.CeMitarb, System.Nullable`1<int>> (Genesis.DataAccess.Schema.Mobile.V1.Wrapper.CeMitarb)' while running with --aot-only.

  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToLookup[CeMitarb,Nullable`1,CeMitarb] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 keySelector, System.Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) [0x00079] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs:2966 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToLookup[CeMitarb,Nullable`1] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs:2934 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateJoinIterator>c__Iterator18`4[Genesis.DataAccess.Schema.Mobile.V1.Wrapper.CsUser,Genesis.DataAccess.Schema.Mobile.V1.Wrapper.CeMitarb,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],Genesis.DataAccess.Schema.Mobile.V1.Wrapper.CsUser].MoveNext () [0x00023] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs:1157 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Genesis.DataAccess.Schema.Mobile.V1.Wrapper.CsUser].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Genesis.DataAccess.Schema.Mobile.V1.Wrapper.CsUser]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 collection) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[CsUser] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.QuickSort`1[Genesis.DataAccess.Schema.Mobile.V1.Wrapper.CsUser]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Linq.SortContext`1 context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.QuickSort`1+<Sort>c__Iterator2F[Genesis.DataAccess.Schema.Mobile.V1.Wrapper.CsUser].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[CsUser] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at CSMobile.Logic.Forms.Login_Dal.GetUsersSqlCount () [0x00000] in /Volumes/Mobile2011/Mobile 2011/trunk/WinCE/CSMobile/CSMobile.Logic/Forms/Login.Dal.cs:38 
  at CSMobile.Logic.Forms.Login_Logic.GetUsers () [0x0001f] in /Volumes/Mobile2011/Mobile 2011/trunk/WinCE/CSMobile/CSMobile.Logic/Forms/Login.Logic.cs:198 
  at CSMobile.Logic.Forms.Login_Logic.Anmelden2 (Int32 selectedProduct) [0x00050] in /Volumes/Mobile2011/Mobile 2011/trunk/WinCE/CSMobile/CSMobile.Logic/Forms/Login.Logic.cs:416 
  at CSMobile.UI.Login.Logic_LoginStepCompleted (Login_StepResult result) [0x0003e] in /Volumes/Mobile2011/Mobile 2011/trunk/IOS/CSMobile/CSMobile.UI/Forms/Login.cs:325 
  at CSMobile.Logic.Forms.Login_Logic.Anmelden1 () [0x00084] in /Volumes/Mobile2011/Mobile 2011/trunk/WinCE/CSMobile/CSMobile.Logic/Forms/Login.Logic.cs:364 
  at CSMobile.UI.Login.StartLogin () [0x00000] in /Volumes/Mobile2011/Mobile 2011/trunk/IOS/CSMobile/CSMobile.UI/Forms/Login.cs:75 
  at CSMobile.UI.Login.Pad_Start_TouchUpInside (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender) [0x00000] in /Volumes/Mobile2011/Mobile 2011/trunk/IOS/CSMobile/CSMobile.UI/Forms/Login.cs:235 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00042] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:29 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:34 
  at CSMobile.UI.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0000a] in /Volumes/Mobile2011/Mobile 2011/trunk/IOS/CSMobile/CSMobile.UI/Main.cs:18 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'System.Linq.Enumerable:<ToLookup`2>m__5A<Genesis.DataAccess.Schema.Mobile.V1.Wrapper.CeMitarb, System.Nullable`1<int>> (Genesis.DataAccess.Schema.Mobile.V1.Wrapper.CeMitarb)' while running with --aot-only.
```

Comment: Please fill a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and we'll look if this is fixed in the latest alpha releases (5.3.x) that solves many of those issues. If not it will be added to our test suite and you'll be notified once this is fixed (and in most case we'll be able to give you a workaround based on your test case).

Answer (score 1):

I think this limitation here is actually due to Generic Virtual Methods - http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations#Generic_Virtual_Methods

There's a discussion of a very similar problem on the mailing list:

- http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/LINQ-JIT-error-again-td3800970.html;cid=1338984263803-35#a3800169

It didn't sound like that thread found a solution

It might be worth contacting Xamarin support directly on this one. http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: i fount this dicsussion too, I´m very confused. It worked perfectly on Monday till Thursday. On Thursday evening it got broken. On those days it worked on my iPad without any Problems. And i´m really sure that i haven´t changed anything in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are a bit weird on MonoTouch due to AOT compilation. A true runtime / JIT is disallowed in iOS, so it must compile everything ahead-of-time.

In this particular case, your method which returns `IEnumerable<CsUser>` is most likely the culprit. [Generic interfaces cause problems](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT#Limitation%3a_Generic_Interface_Instantiation). Try changing your return type to a `List<CsUser>` or any other concrete class that implements `IEnumerable<CsUser>`.

Comment: Ok, now i tried it with List<CSUser>. Doesent work! It works perfect on the simulator but not on my device.

Comment: @Alex the simulator uses the JIT compiler (not the AOT compiler) to ensure the fastest development cycle (edit, build, debug) possible. There are other differences between the simulator and devices but most of them are not related to MonoTouch.

Answer (score 0):

OrderBy is known to fail in this scenario.  This appears to be fixed in MonoTouch version 2.10 but unfortunately if you're using an engine like Unity, that only ships with 2.6 currently (as of 4.3.x).

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2155#c11

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a convenient solution for Xamarin at the moment.
However there is such a solution for Unity 3D.

You can try [LINQ to iOS](http://linqtoios.pgames.guru/). It's a custom implementation of LINQ to Objects extension methods that works on iOS without JIT-compile errors. If you're using Xamarin you may try to take .dll from LINQ to iOS and use it in your project. After all, Xamarin and Unity both use Mono compiler.